# No Authorization to access your own files from your own notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

I wonder if there's any possibility that we could "shortcut" the Google Drive mounting security question workflow (you have to switch context twice, and scroll), if, and only if, the Google Drive in question being mounted is "Yours", and the Colab you are running is "Yours".

I realize that the notion of "Yours" might be a bit hard, but it feels like that it already knows who I am (it prepopulates the thing to tap with my gmail id).

It just feels so clunky, given that the Colab lives in exactly the same Gdrive as my Data files...

Thanks in advance,
Winton

Comment: Well, now you added support for things like SSH authentication to github (yay!!! thank you for this), Can we please please have a "If I am the "owner" of this colab, Please let me access my drive directory without having to go through the double pop up oauth hassle please" option!!